# Retrieving the cpu, gpu specs on a deployed Deep Learning VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, google-dl-platform

I already deployed a Deep Learning VM by configuring cpu and gpu. I would like to retrieve that information.

Is there a way to find out what gpu and cpu specification my deployed DeepLearning VM has?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the CPU and GPU of your Deep Learning VM by navigating to your Vertex AI and then select workbench you can see their the machine type and GPU.